# Why wi-fi calling turned off on reconnection of wi fi?

Tags: wi-fi, calls, redmi

I am not getting any no cellular network at my home and I have broadband connection. When I go in cellular network area turn on mobile data and came back to home my wi fi calling works perfectly, however if I go away from wi fi network for few minutes and came back or wi fi restarts due to power failure then wi fi calling is automatically off.
I need to connect cellular network again  in order to re-enable wi fi calling.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi calling isn't something which enables free calls over wifi.
Your SIM ISP operator needs to make sure you're on an active pack with voice facility available before allowing wifi calling. That's why you need to be on mobile network each time you connect to wifi calling service; and it stays toggled on on wifi calling mode before wifi drops for some reason according to the same logic.